# Site at first load very slow IIS debug

Tags: performance, debugging, iis, traffic

Our live website is loading very slow at first request and I need to dig deeper in IIS/Server. Do you have any tricks that could help me investigate and resolve this without any 3rd parties tools?

Comment: Do mean asp.net applications ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to consider

1. Change IIS/Application Pools configuration to use `startMode="AlwaysRunning"` this causes to w3wp process spawning just after you start Application Pool (this reduces a bit of time with first request)
2. Start using [Application Initialization Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization), it may require some implementation but in basic setup can reduce time of first request at least several seconds
3. Alternatively you can use [IProcessHostPreloadClient](https://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2012/07/how-to-use-iprocesshostpreloadclient) but it's specific to ASP.NET applications

If we are talking about application deployment process you also need to know that there are 2 concepts (if we are talking about .net applications) IIS Application Pool and .Net `AppDomain` https://www.treeloop.com/blog/iis-application-domain-and-pool-recycling so 2 and 3 may behave diferrently

Answer (score 0):

IIS must compile the application when the first request come. That's why IIS cost so much time to return first response. Please application initialization.

[application-initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)